# Isomorphism of quotient rings of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-a)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-b)$. Which $a$ and $b$ must be?

Of course when $a$ equal to $b$, but I can't find any others. I tried to divide $(x^2-a)$ to $(x-\sqrt{a})\cdot(x+\sqrt{a})$, but with no success

Comment: What are `a` and `b`? What is `Zx`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-b)$ there is an element $\beta$ such that $\beta^2=b$ and similarly for the other ring.

Prove that, since $x^2-b$ is monic, every element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-b)$ can be represented in a unique way as $m+n\beta$ (where $\beta^2=b$ and $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$).

By the isomorphism, there are $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
(m+n\beta)^2=a
$$
which means
$$
m^2+bn^2+2mn\beta=a
$$
so, by the uniqueness of the representation, we have
$$
\begin{cases}
m^2+bn^2=a\\
mn=0
\end{cases}
$$
The case $n=0$ means $a$ is a perfect square, so $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-a)\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and the same must hold for the other ring, so…

The case $n\ne0$ and $m=0$ says that $bn^2=a$. Can you go on? Use the fact that we can assume $a$ and $b$ aren't perfect squares.